# How do I read a local access database file from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-access

I would like to edit a Microsoft Access Database that is local to the client and not the server. I am able to open/read/understand an excel file on the client but I don't know how an access db is saved. The user should be able to upload a db file and have the contents displayed on the webpage. Is this even possible?

Comment: as in an SQL file?

Comment: it uses sql but it is a Microsoft access file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully how you want this to work - I have often used MS Access databases from local webpages but only with IIS enabled, so that you can connect to the DB with ODBC, or whatever. But I have only made that work with ASP or PHP. If that's what you want, then I can explain, otherwise you need people better than me.

Comment: it's a website that is sent to the client for them to use on the microsoft access database to get metrics from the data, so no.

Comment: @TonyDuffill /^

Answer (score 0):

In order to read an access database, you would need an OLE DB Driver.

You can use some scripting with ActiveX. Browser permissions needs to be set, before you can use ActiveX and also would require the Microsoft.Jet drivers installed on the client. If they had an access installed, they would probably have this driver.

```
var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='/\dbName.mdb'");
rs.Open("Select * From mytable", cn, 1, 3);
```